# 3D symmetry search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, 3d, theory, symmetry

This may be more appropriate for math overflow, but nevertheless:

Given a 3D structure (for example, a molecule), what is a good approach/algorithm to find symmetry (rotational/reflection/inversion/etc.)?

I came up with brute force naïve algorithm, but it seems there should be better approach.
I am not so much interested in genetic algorithms as I would like best symmetry rather then almost the best symmetry

there is this here: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci990322q from my field.  would be good to know what mathematicians/computer science people came up with as well.

A link to website/paper would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [website for Symmetry Detection and Structure Discovery research](http://www.agg.ethz.ch/research/symmetry).  The papers at the bottom include the one that @Xavier Ho mentions.

Answer (score 3):

This paper should get you started:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~niloy/research/approx_symmetry/paper_docs/approx_symmetry_sig_06.pdf